# iphone app web view not appearing on device

Tags: iphone, twitter, view, webview, controller

i have a view controller and in view did load method i have this code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    self.navigationItem.title=@"Twitter Profile";
    CGRect webFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 370.0);
    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:webFrame];
    [webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    NSString *urlAddress = @"http://twitter.com/#!/SummerApps";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
    [self.view addSubview:webView]; 
    [webView release];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

in simulator everything works fine but on device the page just doesn't load.
I also have the same code on another view for facebook and it works fine the link is the only difference! Any help?

Comment: Try to put this code into viewDidAppear

Comment: in simulator it doesn't work! just a white background

Comment: [super viewDidLoad]; is in the middle of the method?

Comment: no it's in the end of the method

Comment: also on device it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well when i open the same link with safari on my i-device pops up an alert that tells me that the certificate is not trusted if i click ok then it loads? Do you know whats going on i think that's why it doesn't load in my built in web view

Answer (score 1):

have you connected your webView with outlet connection ? or check your internet setting in Simulator.

Comment: yeah i think it's a twitter problem asks for a certificate on mobile safari so can't appear on webview